# Can't get scientist.js to run error handler

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am learning how to use [scientist](https://github.com/trello/scientist). Overall, it seems to work fine, but I can't get the error-handling capability to work. Example:

```
const Scientist = require('scientist');
const scientist = new Scientist();

scientist.on('error', error => {
    console.log('Error during experiment:');
    console.log(error);
});

const science = scientist.science.bind(scientist);

const calculateSum = (a, b) => {
    return science('sum', experiment => {
        experiment.use(() => a + b);
        experiment.try(() => { throw new Error('oops') });
    });
};

calculateSum(1, 1);
```

If I run this, I see `2` on the console, as expected, but nothing else. I would expect to see `Error during experiment:` but I don't. **Why is the error handler not running?** Is this a bug in scientist, or am I doing something wrong? I am using scientist v1.1.1 and Node v8.11.1 on macOS 10.13.6.

I am able to get the `scientist.on('result')` handler to run (not shown in my example).

Comment: I just realized that this question is confusing. scientist and scientist.js are 2 different packages on npm. I originally used scientist, but I realized that it is not actively maintained, so I may give up on trying to make it work and use scientist.js. I am going to keep this question here in case it may be of benefit to anyone.